# Get value of a span inside the div when other span is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is the structure that I have:

```
<div class="div1">
    <span class="span1">
       <span class="span2">X</span>
       <span class="span3">some text</span>
    </span>   
</div>
```

Question that I have when I click on the `span2`, is how to pick up via alert for example text of `span3`?

Comment: What did you try ?

Comment: Do you want the other way around too (when click on `span3` show `span2` text)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**jQuery**

```
$('.span2').on('click', function() {
    var $span3 = $(this).closest('.span1').find('.span3');

    console.log($span3.text());
});
```

**[Check Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1udtgkn0/)**

**Vanilla JS**

```
let span2 = document.querySelectorAll('.span2');

Array.from(span2).forEach(function(elem) {
        elem.addEventListener('click', function() {
            let span3 = this.parentNode.querySelector('.span3');

            console.log(span3.innerHTML);
      });
});
```

**[Check Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1udtgkn0/1/)**

You would need to target the closest parent which is `span1` here that contains `span3` and then get the text of that element.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using jQuery you've several choices so you could use **[`.parents()`](https://api.jquery.com/parents/)** or **[`.siblings()`](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/)** or **[`.next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/)** or also `closest()` (as shown in *Sushanth's* answer), to target the related `.span3` span :

```
$('.span2').on('click', function(){
    $(this).parents('.span1').find('.span3').text();
    //Or
    $(this).siblings('.span3').text();
    //Or
    $(this).next('.span3').text();
})
```

Hope this helps.

```js
$('.span2').on('click', function(){
    console.log( $(this).parents('.span1').find('.span3').text() );
    //Or
    console.log( $(this).siblings('.span3').text() );
    //Or
    console.log( $(this).next('.span3').text() );
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div1">
  <span class="span1">
    <span class="span2">X</span>
    <span class="span3">some text</span>
  </span>   
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** Changed it if there are mutliple sets.

Here's a JavaScript example using `.nextElementSibling` property:

**SNIPPET**

```js
var d1 = document.querySelector('.div1');

d1.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  var txt = e.target.nextElementSibling.textContent;
  alert(txt);
}, false);
```

```css
.span2 {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.span3 {
  pointer-events: none
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">
  <span class="span1">
       <span class="span2">X</span>
  <span class="span3">some text 1</span>
  </span>
  <br>
  <span class="span1">
       <span class="span2">X</span>
  <span class="span3">some text 2</span>
  </span>
  <br>
  <span class="span1">
       <span class="span2">X</span>
  <span class="span3">some text 3</span>
  </span>
  <br>
  <span class="span1">
       <span class="span2">X</span>
  <span class="span3">some text 4</span>
  </span>
</div>
```